# how can replace and rename to same variable

Tags: python-3.x

how can I shorten it and do it in a line?

```
latest_dir = "test for test"

new_name = latest_dir.replace(' ', '_')
os.rename(latest_dir, new_name)
latest_dir = new_name
```

I want to rename the directory from

```
test for test
```

to

```
test_for_test
```

but it should keep the variable latest_dir

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.8+ you can do it in one line with an assignment expression:

```
os.rename(latest_dir, (latest_dir := latest_dir.replace(' ', '_')))
```